# What are access token and refresh token from firebase auth result

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I set up my APP and can get an auth result by using `firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('google.com')`. Inside the returned result, there is an `User` object that contains `refreshToken`. Is this the refresh token generated by `google.com` so I can use it later to refresh an access token which will be used to access gmail?  I am talking about this field [google reference].(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#refreshtoken)

My second question is where is the `access token` from `google.com`? Is it the `credential.idToken`?

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("google.com");
    const currentUser = auth.currentUser;

    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.user) // contains `refreshToken`
      console.log(result.credential.idToken) // is `idToken` access token?
    }).catch((reason) => {
      reject(reason);
    });
```

Comment: Your statement about the refresh token is likely correct.  Not sure about where to find the access token.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the relevant code in use here, not just a line from it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added. Does the question make sense to you now?

Comment: Best guess: it's an identifier used to track some marketing-social media archetype. Like a metadata id code.